# Suggestion handlebar not working (twitter typeahead)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I have just moved over to twitter typeahead v0.11.1 and it is giving me some problems, some of which I have managed to correct. Currently my typeahead is working fine, however when I implement the `suggestion: Handlebars.compile` my code does not work.

This is what I currently have.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var subject = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('sub_name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: 
    {
      url: 'search_sub.php?key=%QUERY',
      wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
});
$('#custom-templates .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'subject',
    display: 'sub_name',
    source: subject,
    templates:  
    {
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile("<div><strong>{{sub_name}}</strong> – {{id}}</div>")
    }       
});
</script>
```

Comment: how does your code not work? can you provide more information?

Comment: if I omit `suggestion: Handlebars.compile("<div><strong>{{sub_name}}</strong> – {{id}}</div>")` it works. However I want to add extra stuff to the search. That means there is something going on wrong with getting the parameters `{{sub_name}}` or `{{id}}` or both. or maybe handlebars is not the right approach.

Comment: may be you need to pass json as argument after compile like  Handlebars.compile("<div><strong>{{sub_name}}</strong> – {{id}}</div>")({sub_name:"Name", id:2})